# Add a sound when receiving new order

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i need help with adding a sound when i receive a new order, i have an autorefresh at 1min and also i have an embedded sound. but i want to play that sound only if a new order arrived not at every refresh, and i dont have any idea right now how to make it.

```
$query="select * from Order where Stare=0 order by ID_Order desc";
    $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die("query failed: " . mysql_error());   
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id_order=$row['ID_Order'];
            $id_oferta=$row['ID_Oferta'];
            $nume=$row['Nume'];
            $prenume=$row['Prenume'];
            $nume_tot=' '.$nume.' '.$prenume.'';
            echo'<tr><td>'.$id_order.'</td>
                     <td>'.$id_oferta.'</td>
                     <td>'.$nume_tot.'</td>
                </tr>';

                 echo'   <embed src="sounds/button-9.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true" name="jukebox"> ';

        }
```

Comment: Why not just put a condition to check if there is a new order, then play the sound or not.

Comment: jeron gave the good answer, first u need to keep the value of the last order and at refresh u need to compare last order with the last row and if it's different u play the sound, thnx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the state of you last query and compare it with the current one.

You could use sessions for that:

```
// at the top of your script
sesstion_start();

  // in your loop
  $last_order = ID_of_the_first_row_found;    // only save the first row ID, use a boolean or counter to keep track of that

// after your loop
if (!isset($_SESSION['last_order']) || $last_order !== $_SESSION['last_order'])
{
  // add the sound
}
$_SESSION['last_order'] = $last_order;
```

Ideally you would do the refresh in javascript using ajax so that you don't have to refresh the whole page and get a nicer user experience.

Comment: Hey thnx a lot, i didnt use a counter i just selected last row from the table, it worked perfect thnx again :)